# Does string[]a = Console.Readline() is the same as string[]a = new string[]?

Tags: c#, string, console-application

My question is if

```
string[] line = new string[3];
 line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

it's the same as

```
string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

Does the second method allocates dynamic memory just as the first one?

Comment: Simple answer no... this really could have been easily testable, use the debugger.

Comment: First one is allocating a memory for an array of 3 strings, second one just assign a result of `Split` function to a variable and your can have more (or less) then 3 items

Comment: Well, the *result* (in particular, the contents of line at the end of the statements) is the same (assuming identical Console input). An optimizing compiler may (or even *should*) eliminate the first allocation because it can see that the allocated object is never used. In that case the IL code produced by the compiler in both cases will be identical as well.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjSBAAwDaAuogDYCWAdgKaIC8iXgHdkDRvGYBubJ14C0Aey4BnRWx4A6AEo8AhgBMAMtx4VNAZQAOnAC6kA5IgfkZMGgF9qOb7gTIiADkKKnc/cVY5PkFUZTUNHX1jU3NrO0dnV1gPDyA===

Comment: @fubo That's very sad ;-). Is it because the array may be referenced from external? But it's not pinned or anything...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ And what exactly is off-topic about this?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Also note that if you want to use the debugger you usually produce an (unoptimized) debug build which does not do away with redundant code, closely mimicking the original source. It is *expected* that  each C# statement produces correspondent IL, so the answer for debug builds is "most likely the produced code is different". That's not so clear for release builds, even though fubo's link seems to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the same thing.

For both options, the final memory used by the `line` variable is allocated by the `Split()` method. In the first option, there's also an extra `string[3]` object wastefully allocated on the first line which is never used and immediately becomes eligible for garbage collection.